# Toast message display - while editing the textfield

Tags: ios, toast

I have implemented the toast message in my application.and it is working fine. while editing the page also, i want to display the toast message. is it possible?

Thanks advance.

Answer (score 0):

First set the textfield delegate method in your controller,

then use its method like,

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

      // display your message here
    return true
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i have added the scrollview. that's y i have troubled with this. thank you for your help.